# Error with jetson-io.py and Python3-curses on Jetson Nano

Tags: linux, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am encountering the following error when trying to use the `jetson-io.py` tool on Jetson Nano:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/init.py", line 78, in wrapper
cbreak()
_curses.error: cbreak() returned ERR

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/nvidia/jetson-io/jetson-io.py", line 594, in <module>
curses.wrapper(JetsonIO)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/curses/init.py", line 100, in wrapper
nocbreak()
_curses.error: nocbreak() returned ERR
```

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

- Expanded the terminal window.
- Executed the `stty sane` command.
- Attempted `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade python3-curses`.
- Tried `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev`.

However, the issue persists. Thank you for your assistance!

Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue or any additional steps I can take for troubleshooting?

Thanks,
Emir